# IDictionary indexer not consistent?

Tags: .net

Why is the Indexer of a IDictionary not implemented the same way?

Look at `Dictionary<Key, Value>` if you try to access something that does not exist it throws a KeyNotFoundException.

If you do the same with a `Hashtable` it returns null.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cp5K7

Comment: `Hashtable` was in the initial version of the framework (1.1). `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` was introduced in version 2 of the framework which was a pretty significant update. As to "why"? You will have to ask the people that designed `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. My guess is as good as yours but it is not unheard of that frameworks that are backwards compatible become inconsistent over time.

Comment: Consider the fact that a `Dictionary` can hold pairs like <34, null> and it has a meaning... Returning null when key does not exists would then be dangerous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main reasons: generics and arbitrary restrictions.

First, for any reference type, `null` is a perfectly valid value, and separate from the existence or non-existence of a key in a dictionary. So `Hashtable` limits your ability to distinguish between a non-presence and a `null` value. This can hide errors.

Second, the dictionary type is generic, and allows value types. Value types have no notion of `null`, or anything similar.

As .NET progressed, more and more weight was put on preventing "bad paths" through code - making ambigous things obvious by making them an error by default. `dictionary[42]` means "I assume the dictionary contains the key 42, and I want the value associated with the key", just like `array[3]` means "I assume the array contains at least four elements, and I want the fourth one". `Hashtable`'s treatment of the indexer is the weird one, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a lot of explanations and no one answer, but: How would a `Dictionary<string,int>` return null?